# how can i use lighting from vertex color and a texture at the same time

Tags: colors, shader, lighting, vertex

My model is lighted in 3ds max with the lighting baked on vertex color, on the other hand a texture is tiling along the model.

So, how could I mix both vertex lighting and texture sampling?